# Doubly-linked lists in Core Data

Tags: core-data, doubly-linked-list

I haven't found an answer on SO for a doubly-linked list implementation in Core Data.

Here's my object model:
[image]

It's a simple music playlist, with each song (URL) being a separate element.  All relationships are to-one without inverses.  I understand that inverses are often needed to make things work efficiently for inserts/deletes in the CD store, so that could be a required but not terribly useful addition.

Inserting and deleting elements would make use of the standard doubly-linked list methods.

**Is this all that's required for a doubly-linked implementation in Core Data?**

Comment: Why isn't prevElem be the inverse relationship of nextElem?

Comment: With your proposed inverse relationship(s) -- including next being the inverse of prev -- a simple insert between nodes 1 and 2 could become:

Node1.nextElem = newNode;
Node2.prevElem = newNode;

Comment: No, inverse relationships takes care of this for you. `Node1.nextElem = newNode` implicitly does `newNode.prevElem = Node1`. Without inverses, you'd had to set them manually and could potentially assign the inverse to the wrong node.

Comment: Patrick... thanks for the comment -- I believe my comment is correct as I'm setting Node2.prevElem and not Node1.prevElem as you imply.  In other words, my doing Node2.prevElem = newNode also does newNode.nextElem = Node2.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I think I misread your comment. What you have said is correct.